# I am facing sonar suggestion issue that Method has 8 parameters, which is greater than 7 authorized in my code

Tags: java

I am facing sonar issue in my below code.

Where sonar suggests that Method has 8 parameters, which is greater than 7 authorized. So how can we solve this issue by putting this parameters in array or map?

```
private void appendSchemeSpecificPart(StringBuilder sb,
    String opaquePart,
    String authority,
    String userInfo,
    String host,
    int port,
    String path,
    String query
)
```

I am not able to make array and pass it to this method `appendSchemeSpecificPart()`.

Can someone help on this?

Comment: Why are you passing a `StringBuilder` object , are you using it after the method call ?

Comment: You can either introduce a parameter object or use a builder pattern instead of constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of host and port is called a socket address. There is already a class for holding this pair of values: [`InetSocketAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html).

By combining 2 parameters into 1, you will not exceed the threshold. You could also see whether other related parameters could be combined.

It almost looks like `String host, int port, String path, String query` are in fact just a URL, but hard to say without seeing the implementation.

Comment: @aniketkanojia edit your question with the information

Comment: Thanks this code worked out for me with InetSocketAddress.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an array to pass several objects that have different semantics.
It is very very error prone.
Instead of, extracting parameters with high cohesion in a class : `SchemeSpecificPart` and define it as a parameter such as :

```
void appendSchemeSpecificPart(StringBuilder sb, SchemeSpecificPart schemeSpecificPart){..}
```

The `StringBuilder` is not a part of the `SchemeSpecificPart` concept. So we will not define it in.

Now you can invoke your method :

```
StringBuilder sb = ...;
SchemeSpecificPart part = ...;
appendSchemeSpecificPart(sb, part);
```

---

Not your question but note that modifying the parameters state (here `StringBuilder sb`)through invoked methods is a unsafe approach.
It gives to the `appendSchemeSpecificPart()` method more responsibilities than it needs. For example, the method could remove existing content for `sb` while it should not be able) and it also may make harder to understand what each method that accepts the `StringBuilder` does really since all methods can overwrite the things done by the previous.

Returning a String appears more clear and robust :

```
String computeSchemeSpecificPart(SchemeSpecificPart schemeSpecificPart){...}
```

And use it :

```
SchemeSpecificPart part = ...;
StringBuilder sb = ...;  
sb.append(computeSchemeSpecificPart(part));
```

Comment: Yeah, you cannot use array nor arraylist for this as they are of different types...Is there any other way to declare.

Comment: In fact no you could use `List<Object>` or `Object[]` but you will finish with a ton of unsafe conversion.  Composite fields with high cohesion in a same class is really the right way.  But I think that the StringBuilder should be away. I update.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to understand why you have that issue.

From sonar, this is classified under `brain overload` - the goal is to make the code easier to read and understand.

> A long parameter list can indicate that a new structure should be
>   created to wrap the numerous parameters or that the function is doing
>   too many things.

Try encapsulating some of those fields in a different class and pass an instance of that class to your method.